# Python bot to answer mathematical questions for a remote server

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, captcha

The MSP Tech Club puts on an annual CTF, available [here](https://ctf.oddcoder.com/). I've worked on a solution but was wondering if there's a better way to write it or if I have any particular bad habits showing themselves?

The challenge is to write a script to connect to a server and answer math problems presented to it, it looks like this:

[image]

Answering 500 questions in a small enough timeframe reveals this:

[image]

I've left the netcat server in the code to allow for testing of changes. Since the CTF is public facing I don't think this poses an issue but feel free to remove if I'm breaking any S/O rules.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import socket
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(('195.154.53.62', 1337))

    while True:
        data = b''
        while True:
            chunk = client.recv(4096)
            data += chunk
            if len(chunk) < 4096:
                break

        # our flag contains ALEXCTF, once it's revealed print recevied data and exit
        if 'ALEXCTF' in data.decode('utf-8'):
            print(data.decode('utf-8'))
            break

        # \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        # .{3} matches any  character, except line terminators exactly three times
        m = re.search('\d+.{3}\d+', data.decode('utf-8'))
        expression = m.group(0)

        #properly handle division
        if '/' in expression:
            expression = expression.replace('/', '//')

        result = eval(expression)

        #print results to screen to see script progress
        print(expression + ' = ' + str(result))

        #encode and transfer
        data = str(result).encode('utf-8') + b'\n'
        client.send(data)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My main concern is the use of `eval()` without proper validation (well, the regular expression extraction puts some limits onto the possible `expression` values, but still it can be exploitable). I would either switch to tools like [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) (there are some other options at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)), or, taking into account the simplicity of the possible expressions, map the operator strings into actual operators, something like:

```
import operator


OPERATIONS = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.floordiv  # // operator
}
match = re.search(r'(\d+)\s*([-+*/])\s*(\d+)', data.decode('utf-8'))
if not match:
    raise ValueError("Invalid expression string")

operand1, operation, operand2 = match.groups()

if operation not in OPERATIONS:
    raise ValueError("Invalid operation '%s'" % operation)

result = OPERATIONS[operation](float(operand1), float(operand2))
```

I'm not sure about converting to floats, may be you need [`Decimal`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354423/clarification-on-the-decimal-type-in-python).

Some other notes:

- it is recommended to [use raw strings for regular expression strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871066/what-exactly-is-a-raw-string-regex-and-how-can-you-use-it)
- you can *pre-compile the regular expression* before going into the loop (even though the Python's regex engine is smart enough to cache the compiled patterns implicitly, see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile) for more information)
- error handling - check if the "match" `is not None` before calling `.group()` on it (see how I've done it above)
- fix the typo - "recevied" vs "received"
- comments style - according to `PEP8`, [there has to be a single whitespace after the `#` character](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments)

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. Reading into eval usage more now!

Answer (score 10):

I'd prefer to see more safety, more structured code, and more abstract symbols instead of magic values. There is some inefficiency due to repeated calls that should be cached.

**Safety**

You're connecting to the net. You don't set a limit on the size of your input data, and you don't set a limit on the number of times you will respond to the server.

I think it's not unreasonable to abort if the `data` buffer goes over some upper bound. Realistically, 4k is probably enough. 12k is *definitely* enough.

Likewise, it's probably reasonable to bail out after 100 iterations through the main loop. No sense burning mips beyond that.

Your call to `eval` dangerous. Given that you don't check for re match failures, you should do a better job parsing the expression. Please consider defining a set of accepted operations, explicitly handling them, and not using eval. (Which will make your code look like something from Intro to Programming, but that's more appropriate, really.)

**Structure**

Break your code down into functions. Call them.

Pretty clearly, you "get an expression", "evaluate the expression", and "send the results".

**Symbolics**

These are obvious:

```
MAXBUF = 4096
SENTINEL = 'ALEXCTF'
CTF_BOT = ('195.154.53.62', 1337)
```

There may be more, depending on the expression parsing.

**Caching Results**

You keep calling `data.decode()`. Just stick that result in a variable.